# profile.providerId returns firebase instead of the social provider name

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've successfully create authentication using Twitter with Firebase, but when I do (as indicated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)):

```
if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId)
  });
}
```

it prints out `firebase`. I expected to read `twitter`. How do I know which provider the user signed in with)?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I've seen Firebase returns multiple IDs, Which is unique one?  and I tried with profile.getProviderId(); but I get undefined. I don't know if I explained my problem clearly... As of now If I sign In with Twitter, Facebook or Firebase (with signInWithEmailAndPassword method) when I do profile.providerId I get firebase. Does it exist a method that if I sign in with Twitter it returns me Twitter (or the number id of the social provider), when I sign in with facebook it returns facebook and when I sign in with signInWithEmailAndPassword it returns me firebase?

Comment: The linked question contains your answer. You need to loop over [`userInfo.providerData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#providerData) and check the `providerId` for each of those. `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData.forEach(d => console.log(d.providerId))`. For me this prints `google.com` in my current test.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When you iterate over providerData, what do you exactly test to find which provider was used to log in ?

Comment: I finally found out the answer, but I don't know if and how it's applicable for ionic, so I leave a comment as it nonetheless may help. The provider Id used to login is not given in the providerData. You only have the list of possible providers for the logged user. The provider used to log in is given in the callback when calling SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(). It is not given in the callback when calling SignInWithCredential(), which is the function used in a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this as you refrence variable

```
var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);
```

And Your using this in your init funtion to check if user is logged in or not

```
authObj.$onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

then you should try this for getting provider name and other details

```
function authDataCallback(authData) {
            if (authData) {
                console.log(authData.provider);
               }
            }
```

Hope it will help you out :)